# Looking for a machine learning algorithm that classifies true or false

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, server

I've just got into machine learning. I am looking for an algorithm that could take in several parameters and output true or false. My current project is the take in the characteristics of a server request, (i.e the target url, size of request and body of request) and to decide if the message is a valid message or a potentail ddos. I've been looking into classification algorithm like decision trees. Are there any better ones?

Edit - My explanation is pretty vague. I apologize for that. Let me provide more context.

I have a device that sends data to a server through a proxy. The proxy server is meant to parse through the message and decide if it is a valod message or invalid message, as in if the device is compromised and is veing used in a ddos attack. The parameters that I am looking at to decide if the message is valid or not is the size of the message, the target server and the message type, GET or POST.

I've been looking into decision trees to decide the validity bit i would like to know if there are better ones.

Thank you.

Comment: hi please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic your question is way too broad.

Comment: Thanks Alexis. I've edited my question to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

Try visualising your data before choosing a method PCA (principle component analysis) should be helpful

Depending on how complex the task is something like Linear Discriminant Analysis might be enough

Other classifiers:
Logistic Regression 
Regression Trees and Boosted Trees
Support Vector Machines
Bagging and Random Forest

If the data it too complex for that you should get into 
Neural Nets/ Deep Learning

Most of the methods there can be easily changed to binary